# Leaderboard/scoreboard with a return value

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, dynamic-arrays

creating a scoreboard/leaderboard & i need it to grab the current variables that are set, put them in high score order, then set the new variables with the previous no(eg. if variable 470 is top score, set variable 397 to have a value of 470)
this is where im stuck at:

```
var Sc = [$Variables.value(461), $Variables.value(464), $Variables.value(467), $Variables.value(470), $Variables.value(473), $Variables.value(476), $Variables.value(479), $Variables.value(482)];

Sc.sort(function(a,d){return a < d});
var variable_names = {};

for(var i = 0; i< Sc.length; i++){
   variable_names['sc_'+i] = Sc[i];
}
//console.log(variable_names);
$Variables.setValue(397, variable_names.Sc_0);
$Variables.setValue(398, variable_names.Sc_1);
$Variables.setValue(399, variable_names.Sc_2);
$Variables.setValue(400, variable_names.Sc_3);
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason, why you create a custom meta variable system in javascript? You can put your leaderboard to an object and use this for sorting and output.

Comment: yes i am using a variable and image based application so it restricts quite alot. i have to actually ink the first place variable to then display a certain picture but thats another story lol

Comment: Is there a reason that you set eg. variable_names.Sc_0 but define them in the loop with a small s: 'sc_'+i?

Comment: just a typo. fixed the error but doesnt fix my problem

Comment: What is the last part doing? You are fetching at first the entryvalues, sorting them, adding them into an object and then? Why setting them back to an entry? Should $Variables.setValue(397, variable_names.Sc_0); represent the leading entry?